# Should SSRS 2008 be on a different machine to the database?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have seen recommendations for installing SSRS 2005 and it states that you should separate it from the database engine that hosts the data sources for your reports, that you should not install them on the same server.

Is there any equivalent documentation for SSRS *2008* that provides guidelines/best practices for installation? I am assuming that the same holds true for SSRS 2008 as it did for SSRS 2005 but have not been able to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot point you to any specific documentation.  However, I have visited the Microsoft testing labs in Charlotte, NC several times over the last 5 years to test SQL Server 00/05/08 SSRS based applications and was provided sage advise by the MS SQL experts.

They recommended that no other applications be run on the database server other that the SQL engine.  This included SSRS. This was not easy at all to accomplish in the SQL 2000 product but become much more digestible with the scale-out options in SQL 2008.

It really does depend on the load profile of your application.  You need to test and quantify the engine load verses the reporting load.

One consideration is that the memory and CPU consumption of SSRS '08 is significantly less that '05 due to re-designs in the reporting engine as confirmed by Microsoft and our testing.

My advice would be to load/stress test your application and adjust your hardware and deployment strategy accordingly.  Using Microsoft Testing Labs for this is great environment because they have tons of hardware to test multiple scale scenarios to determine the options for your target deployment scenario.

I hope that provides some insight.

Answer (score 2):

This series of web pages from the SQL Server Customer Advisory Team provides recommendations for SSRS 2008

- [Reporting Services Scale-Out Architecture](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/06/05/reporting-services-scale-out-architecture.aspx)
- [Report Server Catalog Best Practices](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/06/26/report-server-catalog-best-practices.aspx)
- [Reporting Services Scale-Out Deployment Best Practices](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/10/21/reporting-services-scale-out-deployment-best-practices.aspx)
- [Reporting Services Performance Optimizations](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2009/01/14/reporting-services-performance-optimizations.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the list! I was looking for the same thing. Here is another from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272.aspx